# how does the query get distributed in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a question regarding Hive query execution.

Suppose i have a query:

> select * from table where id > 5;

Now this query is converted into a tree and then split into smaller tasks and distributed to the datanodes that  have that particular data.

Now when the query is distributed, does the entire query gets distributed to all the nodes having the data? or does it send only a part of the query to the nodes?

If it sends the entire query to all the nodes, will the data node process only a part of the query or the entire query?

If the above is the case, then what is the use of data nodes processi

Comment: What do you mean by "when the query is distributed"?

Comment: I mean the query is split into small tasks right? when they are distributed among the nodes having data, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Hive generates a MapReduce job or several MapReduce jobs based on the query that you submit. MapReduce jobs are then distributed by the Hadoop JobTracker according to the algorithms that Hadoop uses to distribute tasks of the MapReduce jobs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `distribute tasks` : i.e the configured `Scheduler`